# plot time series and NA values in R

Tags: r

I have been searching for missing values visualization in R and even though there are many nice options, I haven't found a code to get exactly what I need.

My data frame **(df)** is

```
data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              Date = c("01/01/2000","02/01/2000",
                       "03/01/2000","04/01/2000","05/01/2000","06/01/2000",
                       "07/01/2000","08/01/2000","09/01/2000"),
            Site.1 = c(NA,0.952101337,0.066766616,
                       0.77279551,0.715427011,NA,NA,NA,0.925705179),
            Site.2 = c(0.85847963,0.663818831,NA,NA,
                       0.568488712,0.002833073,0.349365844,0.652482654,
                       0.334879886),
            Site.3 = c(0.139854891,0.057024999,
                       0.297705256,0.914754178,NA,0.14108163,0.282896932,
                       0.823245136,0.153609705),
            Site.4 = c(0.758317946,0.284147119,
                       0.756356853,NA,NA,0.313465424,NA,0.013689324,0.654615632)
) -> df
```

And I would like to get a plot similar to the following:

[image: expected plot]

Taking into account that my actual data consists of 51 Sites and around 9,000 dates

Comment: Do you want a chart with 51 lines (one for each site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  # from wide to long
  pivot_longer(!Date, names_to = "sites", values_to = "value") %>%
  # add a column of one an NAs following your data
  mutate(fake = ifelse(is.na(value),NA, 1),
         sites = as.factor(sites)) %>%
  # plot it
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = reorder(sites,desc(sites)), color = fake, group = sites)) + 
  # line size
  geom_line( size = 2) + 
  # some aesthetics
  ylab('sites') +
  scale_color_continuous(high="black",na.value="white") + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        panel.background = element_rect(fill ='white'),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Despite, I prefere something simpler like this:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(!Date, names_to = "sites", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = sites, fill =value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  theme_light() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Good answer. I was working on an alternative using the interruption in geom_line caused by NA values.  Ended up with `df <- df %>%  pivot_longer(., cols = 2:5) %>% 
    mutate(present = !is.na(value)) %>% 
    mutate(height = as.numeric(str_remove(name, "Site.")) * present) 
df$height[which(df$height == 0)] <- NA`  --- Couldn't work out a case_when for this last bit.

Comment: @markhogue Something like this `df %>% pivot_longer(., cols = 2:5) %>% mutate(value2 = case_when(!is.na(value) ~ 1));` ?

Comment: Thanks @s__ I'll post the working answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is similar to the first one, but uses NA values to interrupt the lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
  df %>%  pivot_longer(., cols = 2:5) %>% 
    mutate(present = !is.na(value)) %>% 
    mutate(height = as.numeric(str_remove(name, "Site.")) * present) %>% mutate(value2 = case_when(!is.na(value) ~ height)) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(Date, value2, group = name)) +
    geom_line() + 
        theme(legend.position = "none") +
        scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90))
```

[image]